# Zend Framework refresh

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection

In zend framework,in modules i have differnt modules if XYZ person perform some action in one module how we can reflect the change for another person without reflecting it.for eg :-if XYZ person delete any record it should be reflect in other person module without refresh.

Comment: `person delete any record` you mean delete from db?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX and check for changes every few secons or so.

You can try [this article](http://blog.jtclark.ca/2010/03/zend-framework-and-ajax/) for the begining.